# Como usar uma variável Global em dois códigos Jquery para executar condições?

Tags: jquery, variáveis-globais

Segue exemplo simplificado do que estou fazendo. Preciso verificar se as variáveis passadas antes e que modificariam a Global são verdadeiras no checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var usuario_ok;

  $('#cadastro').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    var c_nome = $('#c_nome').val();
    // Verificar Nome

    if (c_nome.length > 2) {
      var usuario_ok = true;
    } else {
      var usuario_ok = false;
    }
    //alert(usuario_ok);

  });

  $('#cadastro').on('change', '#c_concordo', function() {
    var c_chk = this.checked ? true : false;

    if (c_chk == true && usuario_ok == true) {
      $('#deu_certo').html('OK');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cadastro">
  <input type="text" id="c_nome" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="c_concordo">
</form>
<div id="deu_certo">Ainda não</div>
```

Comment: Estás a re-declarar a variável com `var usuario_ok`. Não devias ter `var` aí.

Answer (score 2):

Em Javascript, uma variável é global se ela for declarada sem `var`, ou declarada no escopo global.

Isso é local:

```
function () {
    var foo = 1;
}
```

Isso é global sempre:

```
bar = 1;
```

Isso também é global, mas se você estiver no escopo global:

```
var ni = 1;
```

Agora, essas três formas podem levar à invocação de horrores cósmicos, em especial quando o seu código crescer e você tiver que dar manutenção. Existe uma maneira mais legível e menos suscetível a erros de você ter uma variável acessível em qualquer ponto do código:

```
window.usuarioOk = true;
```

Se você quiser ter várias variáveis globais assim, é melhor declará-las como propriedades de um objeto. Assim:

```
window.minhasGlobais = {
    usuarioOk: true,
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    palmeirasTemMundial: false
    /*etc.*/
}
```

Assim essas variáveis podem ser acessadas de qualquer lugar, e de uma forma inambígua para quem for ler o código.

Answer (score 1):

Em JavaScript cada função determina um novo escopo de variáveis. E funções declaradas dentro de outras funções enxergam as variáveis externas – a menos que redeclarem variáveis com o mesmo nome localmente. Por exemplo, num código com a mesma estrutura do seu:

```
function externa() {

    var valor = 'externa';


    function primeiraInterna() {
        var valor = 'primeira interna'; // não afeta o valor de fora, e também
                                        // impede acesso ao valor de fora
    }

    function segundaInterna() {
        console.log(valor);             //  tem acesso ao valor de fora
        valor = 'segunda interna';      //  afeta o valor de fora
    }

}
```

Portanto, no seu tratamento de `keyup` não use `var` ao se referir a `usuario_ok`, caso contrário você cria uma variável local e perde acesso à mais externa (que no seu exemplo não é exatamente global).

Answer (score 0):

E so retirar o `var` da variavel `usuario_ok` nessa parte:

```
if (c_nome.length > 2) {
    var usuario_ok = true;
} else {
    var usuario_ok = false;
}
```

Se utilizar o var você vai estar re-declarando a variavel `usuario_ok` por isso não funcionava.

Troque seu código para:

```
if (c_nome.length > 2) {
    usuario_ok = true;
} else {
    usuario_ok = false;
}
```

Código funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var usuario_ok;

  $('#cadastro').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    var c_nome = $('#c_nome').val();
    // Verificar Nome

    if (c_nome.length > 2) {
      usuario_ok = true;
    } else {
      usuario_ok = false;
    }
    //alert(usuario_ok);

  });

  $('#cadastro').on('change', '#c_concordo', function() {
    var c_chk = this.checked ? true : false;

    if (c_chk == true && usuario_ok == true) {
      $('#deu_certo').html('OK');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cadastro">
  <input type="text" id="c_nome" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="c_concordo">
</form>
<div id="deu_certo">Ainda não</div>
```